# SQL vs Elastic results in Regression Tests

Tags: sql-server, azure, selenium, elasticsearch, regression

We have regression tests using Selenium which picks a value from a web page as the actual result. The data in the web UI is sourced from Elastic Search.

The regression tests that have been written are comparing this UI value, directly with the original data in SQL Server before the transfer to Elastic.

My question is:
Should the regression test look for the expected result in SQL Server or Elastic search?

If we pull expected data from SQL server, then we are including the data transfer processing from SQL to Elastic in the test.

If we pull expected data from Elastic, we are just testing the UI and layers down to Elastic, but not the DB --> Elastic configuration.

I can see the benefits of both methods. Any thoughts

Comment: It's obvious, as you already mentioned, that if you test both then you cover more functionality. Bugs can happen in the elastic search implementation and somewhere in the data transfer from the search API to UI. So actually you can have two sets of tests and you will feel safe then :)

Comment: Thanks Alex, the same solution myself and the boss were coming to.